# Prove the series is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to go about proving that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c^n}{n! + n}$$
is absolutely convergent for **every** real number c.

I originally thought of proving the sequence is a null sequence by multiplying through by $\frac{1}{n!}$. However, this would only hold for $|c| <1$ if I’m not mistaken. Also, how to show it is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first consider series $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{|c|^n}{n!}$$ It converges: apply ratio test for $c \ne 0$ (if $c = 0$ the convergence is obvious) $$\frac{|c|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \frac{n!}{|c|^n} = \frac{|c|}{n} \rightarrow 0$$

Then your series $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{c^n}{n! + n}$$ is absolutely convergent by comparison test: $$\frac{|c|^n}{n!} > \left|\frac{c^n}{n! + n}\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n:= \frac{c^n}{n! + n}.$ Then

$$|a_n| \le \frac{|c|^n}{n!}$$

for all $n$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|c|^n}{n!}$ is convergent. The comparison test now gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let us choose an $m>|c|$. For $n>m$ we have

$$\left|\frac{c^n}{n!+n}\right|<\frac{|c|^n}{n!}<\frac{|c|^m}{(m-1)!}\left(\frac{|c|}m\right)^{n-m}.$$

So the requested sum is bounded by the $m$ first terms plus a geometric series with a common ratio less than one.